# Aws dynamo read capacity units and write capacity units

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

The dynamodb table states that:

> **One read capacity unit represents** one strongly consistent read per second, or **two eventually consistent reads per second**, **for an item up to 4 KB in size**. If you need to read an item that is larger than 4 KB, DynamoDB will need to consume additional read capacity units. The total number of read capacity units required depends on the item size, and whether you want an eventually consistent or strongly consistent read.

If I assume I have items(rows) with size of 4KB, and this table has 1 million records.

I want to query this table 1000 times for individual items with a lambda function, and I would like it to be done in four second.

My thinking is that:

1000 items in four seconds, means 250 items read per second.

Since one RCU does two eventually consistent reads per second, I would need 125 RCUs.

Is this correct in thinking?

Furthermore, let's say that two people want to query 1000 items in four seconds at the same time. Does this mean, I would need 250 RCUs?

I also have a lambda function, which writes to this same table on a schedule, It first get's some values from an API and parses it with JSON, then inserts into table.

This lambda function will insert 60 records every hour. Each record will be 4KB, does this mean I would need 240 WCUs to write all 60 in one second?

Due to:

> **One write capacity unit represents one write per second for an item up to 1 KB in size.** If you need to write an item that is larger than 1 KB, DynamoDB will need to consume additional write capacity units. The total number of write capacity units required depends on the item size.

Comment: Roughly yes, you do get some burstability with this, if it's a batch job maybe set up a autoscale to handle batch writes. If you're only writing very infrequently you can keep it a bit lower and dynamo will simply throttle the write slightly. The point of reserving RCUs is for guaranteed 1-10 milisecond read write

Comment: I think you have a solid handle on it. You will also want to take a look at some of the sections at [_Best Practices for Tables
_](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html) to get an understanding of some of the other aspects to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks, just making sure because the prices seem so high for some of my requirements.

Comment: If you want RCUs in bulk for long term, AWS also offers Reserved Capacity (Provisioned Throughput) in which 100 RCUs purchased in advance for a year cost upfront 30$/yr or 36$ when purchased for 3 years. This price is 5x lower than regular RCU prices.